# Save and restore a ButtonText when screen orientation is switched

Tags: android, save, orientation, state, flip

As usual in android, each time the screen is flipped to portrait/landscape mode an Activity runs through life-cycle from onSaveInstanceState to onDestroy and then is recreated.

In my Activity there's a ButtonText which can be changed by the user. It's reseted to the initial state, but I have to save the last state somehow. How can I achieve that, will I have to override onSaveInstanceState? Can someone show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Call `getText().toString()` on the `Button` to get the caption.

Step #2: Call `putString()` on the `Bundle` passed to your implementation of `onSaveInstanceState()` to store the caption.

Step #3: Call `getString()` on the `Bundle` passed to your implementation of `onRestoreInstanceState()` (or in `onCreate()`, if the `Bundle` is not `null`, if you wish) to get your caption back, then call `setText()` on your `Button` to put the caption back in.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationOne/) that uses `onSaveInstanceState()` to save a `Uri` of a contact (which also affects whether or not a `Button` is enabled).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and expected that the default implementation would take care of restoring a button's text. Unfortunately it did not. Finally I found the attribute android:freezesText respectively the method setFreezesText(boolean). When set to true the button will restore its text automatically.

See the reference of Button's super class TextView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText

Comment: This answer works, its as simple as adding `"android:freezesText="true"` to your button XML and button text is saved in orientation changes